# Eclipse hangs during start on OS X after recent upgrades (XCode)

Tags: xcode, eclipse, git, macos

The other day, I have installed the latest updates through the OS X app store. Today, I can no longer start Eclipse. Basically the loading hangs somewhere in the splash screen. I can open an empty workspace, but when trying to open my usual workspace, it hangs.

I am using Eclipse Neon and work on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

If latest updates in the app store included an XCode update (which is the case here), then make sure you run XCode once before running Eclipse, so that you can accept the terms of use. Apparently, the Eclipse GIT plugin has some dependency on XCode.

I discovered this by looking at the log file in the Eclipse workspace which contained lines like this:

```
2016-09-22 08:17:45,781 [Thread-5] ERROR org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS -

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```